# How does autoincrement work internally in a db?

Tags: database, distributed

I understand how to use auto_increment, but how does it work internally? 
Couple questions in different scenarios came to mind:

1. For a single node DB, does it use mutex to lock entire table, while incrementing a counter and assigning the value to a row, to prevent race conditions? Wouldn't it be a performance problem when doing this? If not, how does it guarantee a unique id be generated when multiple requests come in at the same time?
2. For a DB that is replicated, master-master, or master-slave, it wouldn't make sense to lock up the entire DB table on all the replicas for the auto-increment id, would it?
3. For a DB that is distributed (think Cassandra for example), it really isn't possible to have an auto-increment feature, is it? Because the DBs are working independently for fast WRITEs.

How would you design a distributed system that supports auto_increment?

Answer (score 3):

For MS SQL Server, the server caches a number of `IDENTITY` values in memory which are consumed by inserting records (see [TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh407114.aspx)).

In a replication scenario, MS SQL Server requires that `GUID`s are used as primary keys, so no auto-increment here. You could still use `SEQUENCE`s for (additional) auto-increments, though.

Note that neither `IDENTITY` (i.e. auto-increment) nor `SEQUENCE` guarantee consecutive numbers.

Comment: Thanks. So it offloads the job of issuing an IDENTITY value to a centralized in-memory process, which guarantees a unique value generated and issued every time a request came through. And because this is pre-generated in-memory, the issuing part should be fast. Interesting. Thanks for sharing the article.